# RegExp Match all text parts except given words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have a `text` and I need to match all text parts except given words with `regexp`

For example if text is `'   Something went wrong    and    I could   not   do anything   '` and given words are `'and'` and `'not'` then the result must be `['Something went wrong', 'I could', 'do anything']`

Please don't advise me to use `string.split()` or `string.replace()` and etc. I know a several ways how I can do this with build-in methods. I'm wonder if there a regex which can do this, when I will execute `text.match(/regexp/g)`

Please note that the regular expression must work at least in Chrome, Firefox and Safari versions not lower than the current one by 3! At the moment of asking this question the actual versions are 100.0, 98.0.2 and 15.3 respectively. For example you can not use [lookbehind](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) feature in Safari

Please, before answering my question, go to https://regexr.com/ and check your answer!. Your regular expression should highlight all parts of a sentence, including spaces between words of need parts and except empty spaces around need parts, except for the given words

Before asking this question I tried to do my own search but this links didn't help me. I also tried non accepted answers:

[Match everything except for specified strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings)

[Regex: match everything but a specific pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687620/regex-match-everything-but-a-specific-pattern)

[Regex to match all words except a given list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242698/regex-to-match-all-words-except-a-given-list)

[Regex to match all words except a given list (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954185/regex-to-match-all-words-except-a-given-list-2)

[Need to find a regular expression for any word except word1 or word2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030041/need-to-find-a-regular-expression-for-any-word-except-word1-or-word2)

[Matching all words except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107989/matching-all-words-except-one)

[Javascript match eveything except given words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820508/javascript-match-eveything-except-given-words)

Comment: Can you share the actual regexes you've applied that haven't worked?  This just looks like you linked to similar questions without showing how you tried to adapt them to your problem.

Comment: @DanCsharpster You hope that I remember all variants which I tried? :) I tried to a lot of different symbol changing but couldn't adapt them to my problem. If you sure that answer already given in the list of given links, then please share a link to correct answer, but before please check answer on  https://regexr.com/  as I mentioned before

Comment: I'm saying those links are different approaches and how they were applied could make a difference.  One of those might work but there may be an issue with how it was applied.  Sharing actual code would make it easier for people to help you out.  Links are useful for reference but its asking a lot for contributors to look at each of those links and then guess how you applied those techniques to your problem.

Comment: @DanCsharpster the best regexp was `(?!(and|not))\b\w+` but it select words separately but I want the whole parts

Comment: Just in case you drop that terrible Safari browser: `/(?<=^|and|not).*?(?=and|not|$)/g`.

Comment: @PoulBak Unfortunately I can not do this as I did it with IE :) But thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See **Edit** further down.

You can use this regex, which only use look ahead:

```
/(?!and|not)\b.*?(?=and|not|$)/g
```

**Explanation:**

`(?!and|not)` - negative look ahead for `and` or `not`

`\b` - match word boundary, to prevent matching `nd` and `ot`

`.*?` - match any char zero or more times, as few as possible

`(?=and|not|$)` - look ahead for `and` or `not` or `end of text`

If your text has multiple lines you can add the `m` flag (multiline). Alternatively you can replace dot (`.`) with `[\s\S]`.

**Edit:**

I have changed it a little so spaces around the forbidden words are removed:

```
/(?!and|not)\b\w.*?(?= and| not|$)/g
```

I have added a `\w` character match to push the start of the match after the space and added spaces in the look ahead.

**Edit2**: (to handle multiple spaces around words):

You were very close! All you need is a `\s*` before the dollar sign and specified words:

```js
/(?!and|not|\s)\b.*?(?=\s*(and|not|$))/g
```

Updated link: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/6j9ud)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your regexp looks much shorter than in @LukStorms answer but your regexp select an extra space at the start and at the end of selected parts. If you can remove this extra spaces and keep your regexp as short, then it will be great

Comment: I misunderstood the part about spaces, now surrounding spaces are removed from the matches.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please help me again? I want to ignore all empty spaces around need parts. I tried to modify your regexp `/(?!and|not|\s)\b.*?(?=\s*and|\s*not|$)/g` and it ignores all empty spaces around except empty spaces after last part. What do I need to add/modify?

Comment: You missed adding `\w` in the regex, that takes care of that, so my edit is what you want.

Comment: If it doesn't work: Edit your question and include an example, that doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my question. If I have extra empty spaces at the end of sentence then regex will include them too. Here is my [RegExp](https://regexr.com/6j9ud) which I get when tried to adopt your regexp

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a stupid mistake :) Your regexp works perfectly! This  regexp `(?!and|not|\s)\b.*?(?=\s*and|\s*not|\s*$)` also works with just a little difference: You search all parts which started with `\w` but instead of this I ignore leading empty spaces with `|\s`

Comment: Just a little update :) You can write `\s*` only one time at the second part of regexp `/(?!and|not|\s)\b.*?(?=\s*(and|not|$))/g`

Comment: That's absolutely correct and does look better.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible with only using match and lookaheads in javascript.

```
/\b(?=\w)(?!(?:and|not)\b).*?(?=\s+(?:and|not)\b|\s*$)/gi
```

Test on RegExr [here](https://regexr.com/6j8gu)

Basically match the start of a word that's not a restricted word
`\b(?=\w)(?!(?:and|not)\b)`
Then a lazy match till the next whitespaces and restricted word, or the end of the line without including last whitespaces.
`.*?(?=\s+(?:and|not)\b|\s*$)`

Test Snippet :

```js
const re = /\b(?=\w)(?!(?:and|not)\b).*?(?=\s+(?:and|not)\b|\s*$)/gi

let str = `   Something went wrong    and    I could   not   do anything   `;
let arr = str.match(re);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This is beautiful. It trims the extra whitespace around the matches and doesn't capture an empty trailing group either. Just one minor thing, you don't need the `m` flag.

Comment: @Besworks Thx, the `m` can indeed be removed if it's only a string with 1 line. But it's debatable whether it's useful for multiline strings with this regex.

Comment: "Your regular expression should highlight all parts of a sentence, including spaces".

Comment: @PoulBak The expected array doesn't contain the leading nor trailing spaces.

Comment: @PoulBak Sorry if this sentence confused you! I meant to highlight not words separately but with spaces between them. Because I found this regexp `(?!(and|not))\b\w+` and it select all words without space between them